# Javascript Array - showing the index of the lowest number

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Complete JS newbie here!**

I made an Array with a few numbers in it. I added a function that will show me the lowest number. My question can I show the index of the lowest number?(even If I would change the numbers) 
Here is my code in case you need it:

```js
function func()
{
  var low= 0;
  var numbersArr=[29, 26, 44, 80, 12, 15, 40];
  for(var i = 0; i <= numbersArr.length;i++)
  {
     if(numbersArr[i]< numbersArr[i-1])
     {
       low = numbersArr[i];
     }
  }
  console.log(low);
} 
func();
```

Comment: you can with indexOf function , check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Comment: Use numbersArr.indexOf(low).

Comment: To get the lowest number, the following solution may be more elegant: `const lowestNumber = numbers.map(n => n).sort()[0];`. As `sort` mutates, I first create a new array so that the original one is not mutated.

Comment: You can simply use `Math.min.apply` to find min value. No need to write function. and then use `indexOf` to find the index. Check the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function lack the problem of keeping the lowest value, because you compare only the actual element and the element before.

```js
function getLowestValue(array) {
    var low = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // just loop i < array.length!
        if (array[i] < array[i - 1]) {
        //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the problem, you need to check against low
            low = array[i];
        }
    }
    return low;
} 

console.log(getLowestValue([29, 26, 11, 80, 12, 15, 40])); // 12 instead of 11
```

You could store the value of the lowest element and compare with this value.

```js
function getLowestValue(array) {
    var low = array[0],                   // take the first element at index 0
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { // start with index 1, because you need to
                                         // check against the last known smallest value
        if(array[i] < low) {
            low = array[i];
        }
    }
    return low;
}

console.log(getLowestValue([29, 26, 11, 80, 12, 15, 40])); // 11 the right value
```

For getting the lowest index, you could just store the index instead of th value and take it for comparison.

```js
function getLowestIndex(array) {
    var lowIndex = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[lowIndex]) {
            lowIndex = i;
        }
    }
   return lowIndex;
}

console.log(getLowestIndex([29, 26, 11, 80, 12, 15, 40])); // 2
```

Comment: " for (i = 1; i <= numbersArr.length; i++) { // start with 1" - why do I have to start with 1?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually understand it now. :)

Answer (score 3):

> My question can I show the index of the lowest number?

You can do

```
numbersArr.indexOf(low)
```

**Edit**

That said, **your logic of finding the lowest number isn't correct** as you are only comparing the consecutive values of the array, try the updated logic in demo below.

**Demo**

```js
function func() {
  var numbersArr = [29, 26, 11, 44, 80, 12, 15, 40];
  var low = numbersArr[0];
  for (var i = 1; i <= numbersArr.length; i++) {
    if (numbersArr[i] < low ) {
      low = numbersArr[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(low);
  console.log(numbersArr.indexOf(low));
}
func();
```

Comment: @NinaScholz Why is it funny? OP's question was never about finding the lowest number, it was about **find the index of lowest number presumably already found**! Anyways, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can also store value of i in one variable. See below code.

```js
function func()
{
 var numbersArr=[29, 26, 11, 44, 80, 12, 15, 40,10];
  var low = numbersArr[0];
  var indexOfLow;
    for(var i = 0; i <= numbersArr.length;i++)
{
    if(numbersArr[i]< low)
 {
  low = numbersArr[i];
    indexOfLow = i;
 }
}
console.log("Lowest number is : "+low);
console.log("Index of lowest number is : "+indexOfLow);
} 
func();
```

Comment: @NinaScholz I have only added the way to store index. I didn't check the way to find lowest number. I will update my code.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make a function to find minimum value. You can use simply `Math.min.apply` to find minimum value from array and then `indexOf` to find index of that value

```js
var numbersArr = [29, 26, 44, 80, 12, 15, 40];
var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, numbersArr);
console.log("Minimum Value:"+ minValue, "Index is:" + numbersArr.indexOf(minValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:You will declair a variable which will hold the index of low number and assign it in the if statement as shown below:

```
if(numbersArr[i]< numbersArr[i-1])
{
    low = numbersArr[i];
            IndexLow=i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a super easy way to do that, in your way. Just little change in your code. Please take a look.

```
function func()
    {
      var numbersArr=[29, 31, 26, 44, 80, 123, 151, 40,15];
      var low= numbersArr[0];
      var index = 0;
      for(var i = 1; i < numbersArr.length;i++)
      {
        if(low >= numbersArr[i])
        {
          low = numbersArr[i];
          index = i;
        }
      }
      console.log(index);
      console.log(low);
    } 
    func();
```

Hope you found your problem. Happy coding :)